# Change parameter operator in retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a problem with retrofit, I have the following link :

http://localhost:8080/?sort=desc,date:>09/05/2018

In retrofit, when we use @Query it replace all query using = operator but in my case I want :> operator instead of =

```
 @GET("/repositories")
    fun getRepositories(
            @Query("created") date: String ,
            @Query("sort") sort: String = "stars"
    ): Observable<List<Repository>>
```

the result query is : http://localhost:8080/?sort=desc,date=09/05/2018

But I need the following query : http://localhost:8080/?sort=desc,date:>09/05/2018

Comment: :> is not a standard way what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I can't really change the API, I know it's not common, there is also github that use this operator :> in their api for example : https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:>2018-05-10

Comment: but I get the same result even if I replace :> with =

Comment: No the results are different. :> means greater than the date I gave in the parameter you can check the result difference from `total_count`.

Comment: @Danose In the example api https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:2018-05-10  They used q as key and created:2018-05-10 is value.

Comment: @MathaN thank you, you are right I didn't pay attention to q =

Comment: @Danose Welcome :-)